# Create session variables out of looped database values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I am attempting to create a variable from a database array when an HTML link is clicked. The goal is to redirect the user to a form populated using one piece of array data. In other words, the database will be queried and form populated according to which link is clicked (whatever the values of $row[1], $row[2], and $row[3] are).

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$DATE = date('Y-m-d');

require_once 'IRCconfig.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_CHECKIN1 WHERE DATE>='$DATE'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
            <a href="http://localhost/populateClientCheckin.php" class="post">$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]</a>
        </pre>
 _END;
    } 
 ?>
```

If anyone can provide me with some incite as to how I could accomplish this I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: *edited to remove commented out code as it is irrelevant to the question

Comment: first of all, you need to start the session, as simple as `session_start()` on the top of your script. Then, you need to instantiate session variables with the DB values like this: `$_SESSION['var'] = $value`. Afterwards, in the html file or whatever, where the form relies, just check for it: `if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) {}` and use the value if it is set. :D

Comment: are you asking how to send the data from the query to a form located in `populateClientCheckin.php`?  I would use sessions but why create a link to for the user to click? why not just redirect using `header`?

Comment: $row 1, 2, and 3 are the first middle and last names of a particular client. There are numerous clients. I only want to populate the form with the data of a particular client (the one whose link is clicked). Im going to add a screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Nevermind, I need more reputation to post images.

Comment: how much more? at what rep score can you post images?

Comment: I think it said 10, idk, this is only my third time posting on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about sessions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Then, to answer your question:

**First** you need to start the session, as simple as `session_start();` on the top of your script.

**Second** you need to instantiate session variables with the DB values like this: `$_SESSION['var'] = $value;`.

**Third**, in the html file or whatever, where the form relies, just check for it:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
  echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['var'].'" />';
} else {
  echo '<input type="text" value="" />';
}
```

and use the value if it is set.

**L.E:**
So... first thing's first... `session_start();` without it, there is no point of having session.

Second, you create it like `$_SESSION['some_name'] = $row[1]` so that var will keep the value from `$row[1]`. I am presuming that it's the value you need. Do NOT do do it like $_SESSION['$row[1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)'] because first of all this is incorrect, you will NOT have the value of row[1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) there. You need an unique name so that you can call it where you have the form.

The above code will become something like this:

```
<?php 

session_start();

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$DATE = date('Y-m-d');

require_once 'IRCconfig.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$query  = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_CHECKIN1 WHERE DATE>='$DATE'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        $_SESSION['first_row'] = $row[1];
        $_SESSION['second_row'] = $row[2];
        $_SESSION['third_row'] = $row[3];

        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
            <a href="http://localhost/populateClientCheckin.php" class="post">$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]</a>
        </pre>
 _END;
    } 
 ?>
```

and, where you have the form and the `<input type = "text" value = "" />` so where you need the value, just do it like this:

```
<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['first_row']) ? $_SESSION['first_row'] : ''); ?>" />
<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['second_row']) ? $_SESSION['second_row'] : ''); ?>" />
<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['third_row']) ? $_SESSION['third_row'] : ''); ?>" />
```

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: So I would write this (and repeat with $row[2] and $row[3]? I'm not even sure if sessions are the correct thing to use here.                                                          session_start() if(isset($_SESSION['$row[1]'])) {
  echo '<input type="text" value="'.$_SESSION['$row[1]'].'" />';
  }else {
    echo '<input type="text" value="" />';
  }  Sorry about the formatting, not sure how to fix the code in comments.

Comment: check my L.E: ... hope you get the explanation... the last 3 lines you have to place in your <form></form> where you need the values of $row 1,2,3.

Comment: also, I think now you can post that picture ;)

Comment: Short tags are highly discouraged. Don't use `<?= `. Read it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: tx for the input, link and modification... did not knew that :) but doesn't that setting come with php 5.5 by default?